# How can i input latex to wolframalpha api

Tags: wolframalpha

I get problem with latex as the input for wolframalpha api. When i input this expression `x^2 - 49 = 0`, the returned results look fine, but when i input the latex format `x^{2} - 49 = 0` it returns completely different results.

Does any know how to deal with this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
ToExpression["x^{2} - 49 = 0",TeXForm]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).